# 2 way ssl using eclipse paho

Tags: mqtt, paho

How to configure 2 way ssl in MQTT.

Client jar mqttv31.1.0.jar
mosquitto version 1.4.8

---

When using client auth getting error - ssl3_get_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate.

Below is my mosquitto.conf file and java client details:

---

mosquitto.conf

```
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.pem
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.pem
require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true

port 8883
```

---

java client

```
client = new MqttClient("ssl://localhost:8883", "Session_3");
connOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpt.setCleanSession(true);

Properties sslProperties = new Properties();

sslProperties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.TRUSTSTORE, 
"/home/KeyStore.jks");
sslProperties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.TRUSTSTOREPWD, "123456");
sslProperties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.TRUSTSTORETYPE, "JKS");
sslProperties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.CLIENTAUTH, true);

sslProperties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.KEYSTORE, 
"/home/clientStore.jks");
sslProperties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.KEYSTOREPWD, "123456");
sslProperties.put(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.KEYSTORETYPE, "JKS");


connOpt.setSSLProperties(sslProperties);

client.connect(connOpt);

client.subscribe("sample_T");

client.setCallback( new MQTTSampleSubscriber() );
```

---

Getting error

```
MQTT Con: Session_3, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
MQTT Con: Session_3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated: [Session-2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
MQTT Con: Session_3, called closeSocket()
MQTT Con: Session_3, Exception while waiting for close 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: 
handshake_failure
MQTT Con: Session_3, handling exception: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: 
handshake_failure
MQTT Con: Session_3, called close()
MQTT Con: Session_3, called closeInternal(true)
```

---

```
mosquitto log says :

peer did not return a certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

The problem was in server authenticating client i.e in keystore.

While creating keystore remember to add both certificate and key in the jks/p12 files.

e.g

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.pem -inkey client.key -out ClientStore1.p12 -CAfile ca.pem
```